# Who is the enemy fighting Hatchiyack in Dragon Ball Heroes manga chapter 5?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball Heroes manga Hatchiyack appears and he's fighting an enemy which isnt seen in the anime. Who is he?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character you seem to be referring to here is Majin Ozotto. You can read more about him [here](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Majin_Ozotto).